# Can i run C# windows program with mdf file without sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

I build a program in visual studio which has mdf file , I want to run the program on other computer has no sql server it is possible ? if not what I should do

Comment: You need to have LocalDB or SQL Server Express installed and running locally to use mdf files.

Comment: what I should use to create LocalDB

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads  Install this sql server on the local machine and use the connection string in your config file.

Comment: With no SQL Server instance it is not possible. It is the instance the one that provides you the information contained in the MDF file. You have been already given the download link to the SQL Server.

Comment: So you want to use a separate mdf file locally or do you want to connect to the same server on a remote machine?

Comment: i want to use a separate mdf file locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching I know that we should  have LocalDB or SQL Server Express installed and running locally to use mdf files.